# Disable/Enable Triggers From Text Field

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I'm not very familiar with all of the bindings and configs in Ext Js.  So I have a text field with an email (mailto) button.  I want to enable or disable the button **only**.  But I don't know how to begin with handling the trigger itself. So I tried doing a binding in my ViewController like so:

```
txtContactEmail:{
   disabled: {someFunctionInViewModel}
}//this disables/enables the whole control 
 //I only want the trigger button to be disabled/enabled
```

This is the code inside the view created in sencha architect.

```
{
     xtype: 'textfield',
     flex: 2,
     itemId: 'txtContactEmail',
     margin: '0 5 0 0',
     fieldLabel: 'Email',
     labelWidth: 35,
     validateOnChange: false,
     validateOnBlur: false,
     triggers: {
           trgEntityEmail: {
                cls: 'x-form-email-trigger'
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you pls let me know your button is inside of form ?

Comment: form > tab panel > container > text field

Comment: I think you can use **[formBind](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#cfg-formBind)** hope it will help you.

Comment: actually there's no separate button.. the button is just the trgEntityEmail itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just to see binding on a trigger, this inline code can be helpful. It binds the `hideTrigger` config of a textfield to a View Model property. This [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2751) has the working code.

```
 Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
        viewModel: {
            data: {
               x: false
            }
        },
        flex: 2,
        itemId: 'txtContactEmail',
        margin: '0 5 0 0',
        fieldLabel: 'Email',
        labelWidth: 35,
        validateOnChange: false,
        validateOnBlur: false,
        //Bind to x property of View Model
        bind: {
           hideTrigger: '{!x}'
        },
        triggers: {
              trgEntityEmail: {
                   cls: 'x-form-email-trigger' 
                }
        }
    });
```

Another way could be to bind the `hideTrigger` config to some other config of a textfield, eg. value. This inline code shows this approach. You can check it [here.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2752)

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
                viewModel:{},
                flex: 2,
                itemId: 'txtContactEmail',
                margin: '0 5 0 0',
                fieldLabel: 'Email',
                labelWidth: 35,
                validateOnChange: false,
                validateOnBlur: false,
                //Set a reference on textfield and publish its value
                // Use this reference to do the binding
                value: 'Some Value',
                reference: 'mytextfield',
                publishes: ['value'],
                bind: {
                    hideTrigger: '{mytextfield.value}'
                },
                triggers: {
                    trgEntityEmail: {
                        cls: 'x-form-email-trigger'
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: " I want to enable or disable the button only" - to disable the button itself, you should bind `disabled: {!x}` rather than the `hideTrigger` property.

Answer (score 1):

[Ext.field.trigger.Trigger](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.field.trigger.Trigger.html) cant be enabled / disabled out of the box.

I think you can emulate disable state like this

```
var myTrigger = myTextField.getTriggers()['trgEntityEmail'];
// Apply disabled style with .setCls() or .setIconCls()
myTrigger.setIconCls('my-disabled-icon');
// Remove handler
myTrigger.sethandler(Ext.emptyFn);
```

Comment: thanks for the link.. but what i did was disable the button using extraCls= "x-item-disabled"